# While Loop Not Closing When Condition Is Met

Tags: java, while-loop

```
    public void enroll() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter course to enroll (Q to quit)");
        while(!in.nextLine().equals("Q")) {
            courses.add(in.nextLine());
        }
    }
```

The program should accept user input and add it to the ArrayList courses until the user enters "Q" but instead what's happening is that it seems like it's only registering and adding every other input. It's also adding the Q which is an issue.

Comment: You read a line, test if it is "Q" then throw away what you read then read the next line. You need to be storing what you read into a variable so you can use it if it wasn't "Q"

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what you want it to do.
How it should be: users inputs are processed one per iteration and if it's 'Q', then quit while.
How it actually is: users inputs are processed two per iteration(because you cal in.nextLine() both in conditional part and in body of while), and if first is not 'Q' then add second to list.

Here is my code to this:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter course to enroll (Q to quit)");
    String line;
    while(!(line = in.nextLine()).equals("Q")) {
        courses.add(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are getting the next line twice, firstly inside the loop condition `while(!in.nextLine().equals("Q")) {` then again inside the loop `courses.add(in.nextLine());`.

One solution could be to use a string variable to store the line, and an `if` check to see if the condition is met:

```
public void enroll() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter course to enroll (Q to quit)");
    String line = "";
    while(true) {
        //We should only get the next line once per loop:
        line = in.nextLine();
        //Now we can use the line
        if (line.equals("Q")){
            break;
        }
        courses.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually use two logical operations per iteration. One is in while(true), comparing true to true, the other one is in if (line.equals("Q")), comparing true to line.equals("Q"). You could have moved the condition to while(...) block

Comment: @MediaNikOk Yes, for simplicity to help OP see what is happening